# CakePHP adding columns to a table

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, frameworks

I have a Profile model/controller in my cake app as well as an index.ctp view in /views/profiles. Now, when I go to add a column to my table that is already filled with data, and then add the corresponding code to the view to pick up this column's data, it just gives me an empty result.

My model:

```
<?php
        class Profile extends AppModel
        {
                var $name = 'Profile';
        }

?>
```

My controller:

```
<?php
        class ProfilesController extends AppController
        {
                var $name = 'Profiles';
                function index()
                {
                        $this->set('profiles', $this->Profile->find('all'));
                }
        }
?>
```

My views printing (stripped down):

```
<?php foreach ($profiles as $profile): ?>

<?php echo $profile['Profile']['id']; ?>
<?php echo $profile['Profile']['username']; ?>
<?php echo $profile['Profile']['created']; ?>
<?php echo $profile['Profile']['thumbnail'];?>
<?php echo $profile['Profile']['account'];?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Basically, the `columns id, username, column, thumbnail` always have been printing fine, but when I add a column called `account`it returns no information (nothing prints, but no errors). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would delete the files in `app/tmp/cache` (but keep the directories).

Comment: Yep, or ensure `debug = 2` in your app config when developing and it'll rebuild the cache every time

Comment: Check what is the engine (Memcache, File,..) configured as the cache handling engine in the Config/core.php. If it is not 'File', then there will not be file in the temp folder to delete.

Comment: i followed your suggest and now the model is updated , but i still have a problem, i'm using in my controller $this->User->findById($id) to retrieve a user by id, but it still doesnt return the new columns, any hint please ?

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 4, clearing `tmp/cache/models` worked for me.